# How to write distinct and count in a linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an SQL that I am trying convert to Linq Expressions in c#.

Can you please help?

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(alpha))
    sql = "select distinct(Keyword) as word, 
                  count(*) as Counter 
           from Keywords 
           group by keyword 
           order by keyword desc";
else
    sql = "select distinct(Keyword) as word, 
                  count(*) as Counter 
          from Keywords 
          where starts = N'{0}' 
          group by keyword 
          order by keyword desc";
```

I know I have distinct and count in same query, there is no good way I could figure out how to do that? How to I write my LinQ expressions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       int? startFilter = 10;


        var test1 = items.Where(i => startFilter.HasValue == false || i.Starts == startFilter.Value)
                         .GroupBy(i => i.Keyword).Select(grp => new { Keyword = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()})
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: With minor modifications it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could build it up in three parts:

```
IEnumerable<Keyword> query = db.Keywords;

if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(alpha))
    query = query.Where(k => k.starts == alpha)

// need to change from Keyword collection to anonymous type collection
var query2 = query.GroupBy(k => k.Keyword)   
                  .Select(g => new {
                                   word = g.Key,
                                   Counter = g.Count()
                                   }
                         );
```